# Как отключить SLF4J или LOG4j логи в консоле?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Скачал библиотеку и установил ее, но при запуске таймера приложение выводит постоянно логи в консоль (вывод логов прописана внутри библиотеки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:Как отключить отображение логов в консоле?

Comment: `<Logger name="com.github.koraktor.streamcondenser" level="OFF">`

Comment: @notaProgrammer где это прописывать? В поме? Ваш комментарий непонятен

Comment: В `log4j.xml`. Более детально [тут](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: @notaProgrammer а через log4j.properties можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в интернете вариант с добавлением строки:

```java
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
```

Помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас есть Maven, то вставьте следующий dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>
```